# Submit a form to my mail

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

it;s probably the easiest thing to do but I'm a bit stuck. I'v got my form ready, but the submit button on the bottom will not submit the info to my email. I know I did something wrong and there's suppose to be another page which tells the visitor thanks for your submission but I can't seem to find it.

Maybe i'm just tired, but my mind shows blank

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="span12">
  <form class="well" action="submitto:anemailadress@anemailadress.com">  
    <label><b>Klantgegevens</b></label>  <br>
    <span class="inline span2">Winkelnaam</span><input type="text" class="span10">  
    <span class="inline span2">Straat</span><input type="text" class="span10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Verstuur</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

U know PHP ? u will need...

Comment: I'm going to do that :)